# I drew lines in a map using plotly, now i want to color the lines based on the values of a column. How can i color the lines properly?

Tags: dictionary, colors, plotly, line, geopandas

This is the code i'm running. It returns me the following plot:
[Map with lines of the same width and color](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w6Ztj.png).

I want to color the lines with a scale based on the column TKB_Total of my dataframe.

```
lats = np.array([])
lons = np.array([])
names = np.array([])
colors = np.array([])

for linestring, name in zip(mapa_TKB_coord['line'], mapa_TKB_coord['O-D']):
    x, y = linestring.xy
    lats = np.append(lats, y)
    lons = np.append(lons, x)
    names = np.append(names, [name]*len(y))
    
    lats = np.append(lats, None)
    lons = np.append(lons, None)
    names = np.append(names, None)


##I tried this, but i get the error KeyError: (nan, '', '', '', '', '', ''):

rgb = px.colors.convert_colors_to_same_type(px.colors.sequential.RdBu)[0]
rgb.reverse()
colorscale = []
n_steps = 10  # Control the number of colors in the final colorscale
for i in range(len(rgb) - 1):
    for step in np.linspace(0, 1, n_steps):
        colorscale.append(px.colors.find_intermediate_color(rgb[i], rgb[i + 1], step, colortype='rgb'))



fig = px.line_geo(lat=lats, lon=lons, hover_name=names, color=TBs, color_discrete_sequence=colorscale)
fig.show()
```

I have tried mimicking the append logic to an array called TKB and using it inside the line_geo as color=TKB, but it did not work

Comment: In express, color coding is possible by providing a category variable for color. It may be possible in your example, for example, by setting `color=names`. It may also be possible to give a list of color names with the same structure as the array of names. plotly will automatically set the colors and may duplicate them. It would be necessary to create it in a graph object.

Comment: I tried this, but i get the error KeyError: (nan, '', '', '', '', '', ''):

rgb = px.colors.convert_colors_to_same_type(px.colors.sequential.RdBu)[0]
rgb.reverse()
colorscale = []
n_steps = 10  # Control the number of colors in the final colorscale
for i in range(len(rgb) - 1):
    for step in np.linspace(0, 1, n_steps):
        colorscale.append(px.colors.find_intermediate_color(rgb[i], rgb[i + 1], step, colortype='rgb'))



fig = px.line_geo(lat=lats, lon=lons, hover_name=names, color=TBs, color_discrete_sequence=colorscale)
fig.show()

Comment: Depending on whether the data you are using has a single line drawn from the start point to the end point or multiple lines, there will either be a single color name or a series of the same color name. If you have sample data that can be reproduced, we may be able to help.